# PHPのGuzzle 6 でレスポンスヘッダからCookieを読み取りたい

Tags: php

PHPのGuzzle6を使ってレスポンスからCookieを読み取りたいと思っていますが上手くいきません。
アドバイスお願いできないでしょうか。

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['cookies' => true]);

    // ログイン
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://xxxx', [
        'form_params' => [
            'id' => $id,
            'pass' => $pass
        ]
    ]);

    $cookie = $res->getHeader('Set-Cookie');
    echo '<pre>' . var_export($cookie, false) . '</pre>'; // arr() ←空
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

//-- 2016-07-05 追記 --
以下の要領でCookieを取得することができました。

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['cookies' => true]);

    // ログイン
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://xxxx', [
        'form_params' => [
            'id' => $id,
            'pass' => $pass
        ]
    ]);

    // $cookie = $res->getHeader('Set-Cookie');
    $cookies = $client->getConfig('cookies');
    $cookiesArray = $cookies->toArray();
    echo '<pre>' . var_export($cookiesArray, false) . '</pre>';
```

↓取得結果

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Name' => 'xxxxx',
    'Value' => 'yyyyy777362a4c45f95eae7d0ebd59',
    'Domain' => 'example.com',
    'Path' => '/',
    'Max-Age' => NULL,
    'Expires' => NULL,
    'Secure' => false,
    'Discard' => false,
    'HttpOnly' => false,
  ),
)
```

ちなみにHTTPレスポンスヘッダにはSet-Cookieヘッダがセットされていましたが、

```
$res->getHeaders();
```

を利用して見てみたところ、Guzzleのレスポンスオブジェクトには Set-Cookie ヘッダがセットされていませんでした。

Comment: Set-Cookieヘッダが送られてきていれば、提示されているコードで取得できるはずなのですが...実際に叩かれているURLも記載して頂くことは可能でしょうか？また、もう1つの方法として、CookieJarオブジェクトをリクエスト時に指定しておく方法もあります。 http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#cookies

Comment: ありがとうございます！CookieJarも利用してみましたが上手くいきませんでしたので、追記したように対応しました。